# Token.createAccount vs Token.createInitAccountInstruction vs Token.createTransferInstruction in solana. What is the difference

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-program-library, solana-transaction-instruction

I am new to solana and exploring the things.
I came across these terms

```
SystemProgram.createAccount
Token.createInitAccountInstruction
Token.createTransferInstruction
```

What is the difference between these three?

Answer (score 1):

- SystemProgram.createAccount: allocates a certain number of bytes, assigns the account to a program, and transfers the given lamports into the account.  More information about accounts at https://docs.solana.com/terminology#account
- Token.createInitAccountInstruction: after an account has been created, then you can use this instruction to initialize data in the account, specifying what mint it belongs to, who owns it, etc
- Token.createTransferInstruction: after two accounts has been created and initialized, and at least one of them has tokens, you can use this instruction to move tokens from one account to another